# Normalisation and Dirac's Formulation of the Path Integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, path-integral, normalization

Zee's Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell (Dirac's Formulation in Chapter 1.2) contains the following passage (in attached image). Can someone please explain where the normalization is used in getting Equation 3?

[image]

Comment: It is used in the statement $\int d q | q \rangle \langle q | = 1$

Comment: @Prahar I thought $\int dq |q\rangle \langle q|=1$ is true solely because $|q\rangle$ forms a complete set of states.

Comment: No. it depends on the normalization of the states. If $\langle q | q' \rangle = a \delta ( q - q' )$ then $\int dq | q \rangle \langle q' | = \frac{1}{a}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zee uses normalization only to check the completeness relation:

$$\begin{align}
\int dq\ |q\rangle\langle q| &= 1 \\
\langle q''|\int dq\ |q\rangle\langle q|q'\rangle &= \langle q''|q'\rangle \\
\int dq\ \langle q''|q\rangle\langle q|q'\rangle &= \langle q''|q'\rangle \\
\int dq\ \delta(q'',q)\delta(q,q') &= \delta(q'',q') \\
\delta(q'',q') &= \delta(q'',q')
\end{align}$$

Then you need to insert the $1$ operator
$(\int dq|q\rangle\langle q|)$ many times.

$$\begin{align}
  &\langle q_F|e^{-iHT}|q_I\rangle \\
 =&\langle q_F|e^{-iH\delta t}e^{-iH\delta t}\cdots e^{-iH\delta t}|q_I\rangle \\
 =&\langle q_F|e^{-iH\delta t}e^{-iH\delta t}\cdots e^{-iH\delta t}|q_I\rangle \\
 =&\langle q_F|e^{-iH\delta t}
    \overbrace{\int dq_{N-1}|q_{N-1}\rangle\langle q_{N-1}|}^{=1}
    e^{-iH\delta t}
    \overbrace{\int dq_{N-2}|q_{N-2}\rangle\langle q_{N-2}|}^{=1}
    \cdots e^{-iH\delta t}|q_I\rangle \\
 =&\int dq_{N-1}\int dq_{N-2}\cdots
   \langle q_F|e^{-iH\delta t}|q_{N-1}\rangle
   \langle q_{N-1}|e^{-iH\delta t}|q_{N-2}\rangle
   \langle q_{N-2}|\cdots e^{-iH\delta t}|q_I\rangle
\end{align}$$